# In Java, retrieve a JPEG from a URL and convert it to binary or hexadecimal form suitable for embedding in an RTF document

Tags: java, jpeg, rtf, readfile

I'm trying to write a simple RTF document pretty much from scratch in Java, and I'm trying to embed JPEGs in the document. Here's an example of a JPEG (a 2x2-pixel JPEG consisting of three white pixels and a black pixel in the upper left, if you're curious) embedded in an RTF document (generated by WordPad, which converted the JPEG to WMF):

```
{\pict\wmetafile8\picw53\pich53\picwgoal30\pichgoal30 
0100090000036e00000000004500000000000400000003010800050000000b0200000000050000
000c0202000200030000001e000400000007010400040000000701040045000000410b2000cc00
020002000000000002000200000000002800000002000000020000000100040000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000ffffff00fefefe0000000000000000000000
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0000001202af0801010000040000002701ffff030000000000
}
```

I've been reading the [RTF specification](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=DD422B8D-FF06-4207-B476-6B5396A18A2B&displaylang=en), and it looks like you can specify that the image is a JPEG, but since WordPad always converts images to WMF, I can't see an example of an embedded JPEG. So I may also end up needing to transcode from JPEG to WMF or something....

But basically, I'm looking for how to generate the binary or hexadecimal (Spec, p.148: "These pictures can be in hexadecimal (the default) or binary format.") form of a JPEG given a file URL.

Thanks!

---

**EDIT:** I have the stream stuff working all right, I think, but still don't understand exactly how to encode it, because whatever I'm doing, it's not RTF-readable. E.g., the above picture instead comes out as:

```
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
```

[This PHP library](http://www.phprtf.com/) would do the trick, so I'm trying to port the relevant portion to Java. Here is is:

```
$imageData = file_get_contents($this->_file);
$size = filesize($this->_file);

$hexString = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    $hex = dechex(ord($imageData{$i}));

    if (strlen($hex) == 1) {
        $hex = '0' . $hex;
    }

    $hexString .= $hex;
}

return $hexString;
```

But I don't know what the Java analogue to `dechex(ord($imageData{$i}))` is. :( I got only as far as the `Integer.toHexString()` function, which takes care of the `dechex` part....

Thanks all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a file URL for any file you can get the corresponding bytes by doing (exception handling omitted for brevity)...

```
int BUF_SIZE = 512;
URL fileURL = new URL("http://www.somewhere.com/someurl.jpg");
InputStream inputStream = fileURL.openStream();
byte [] smallBuffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
ByteArrayOutputStream largeBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
int numRead = BUF_SIZE;
while(numRead == BUF_SIZE) {
    numRead = inputStream.read(smallBuffer,0,BUF_SIZE);
    if(numRead > 0) {
        largeBuffer.write(smallBuffer,0,BUF_SIZE);
    }
}
byte [] bytes = largeBuffer.toByteArray();
```

I'm looking at your PHP snippet now and realizing that RTF is a bizarre specification!  It looks like each byte of the image is encoded as 2 hex digits (which doubles the size of the image for no apparent reason).  The the entire thing is stored in raw ASCII encoding.  So, you'll want to do...

```
StringBuilder hexStringBuilder = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 2);
for(byte imageByte : bytes) {
    String hexByteString = Integer.toHexString(0x000000FF & (int)imageByte);
    if(hexByteString .size() == 1) {
        hexByteString = "0" + hexByteString ;
    }
    hexStringBuilder.append(hexByteString);
}
String hexString = hexStringBuilder.toString();
byte [] hexBytes = hexString.getBytes("UTF-8"); //Could also use US-ASCII
```

EDIT: Updated code sample to pad 0's on the hex bytes

EDIT: negative bytes were getting logically right shifted when converted to ints >_<

Comment: Thanks Pace, I'm so close now - any idea about the dec/hex/ASCII/etc. encoding bit?

Comment: Hi again Pace - thanks so much for your updates. The *2 in (bytes.length * 2) doesn't seem to change the hexString output, oddly. And the 0-padding seems overeager.

I put together a separate solution (just reading locally for now)--

FileInputStream oStream = new FileInputStream(imagePath);
for(int i = 0; i<oStream.available(); i++) {
 Integer imageBytes = (Integer)oStream.read();
 String imageHex = imageBytes.toHexString(imageBytes);
 if(imageHex.length() == 1) 
  imageHex = "0" + imageHex;
 imageHexString += imageHex;
}
oStream.close();

--and it actually sort of works, but...

Comment: OK, I didn't realize comments didn't preserve line breaks, haha. Point is, the images are only readable in Word, not, say, Win7 WordPad or OS X TextEdit, which is too bad.

As for "over-eager" padding, check out the preponderance of f's in yours: http://pastebin.com/TdZajtVq (does that make sense? I haven't got a clue, haha...)

Anyway, I'm going to check out other options (e.g. http://www.xmlmind.com/foconverter/what_is_xfc.html) since compatibility seems to be an issue....

Thanks again!

Comment: The preponderance of f's was because -1 as a byte is FF but -1 as an int is FFFFFFFF so every negative byte value was getting 6 extra F's.  I edited the above code to fix that.  Note the line Integer.toHexString(0x000000FF & (int)imageByte);

Comment: However, I would definitely recommend using an external library if you plan to use this conversion for something.  If you were doing it as a learning exercise then I think you're close.

Answer (score 0):

https://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2013/07/26/exploring-a-wmf-file-0x000900/

Maybe help you this:

```
        String HexRTFBytes = "Representations text of bytes from Image RTF File";
        String Destiny = "The path of the output File";
        FileOutputStream wmf;
        try {
          wmf = new FileOutputStream(Destiny);
          HexRTFBytes = HexRTFBytes.replaceAll("\n", ""); //Erase New Lines
          HexRTFBytes = HexRTFBytes.replaceAll(" ", ""); //Erase Blank spaces
          int NumBytesWrite = HexRTFBytes.length();
          int WMFBytes = NumBytesWrite/2;//One byte is represented by 2 characters
          byte[] ByteWrite = new byte[WMFBytes];
          for (int i = 0; i < WMFBytes; i++){
            se = HexRTFBytes.substring(i*2,i*2+2);
            int Entero = Integer.parseInt(se,16);
            ByteWrite[i] = (byte)Entero;
          }
          wmf.write(ByteWrite);
          wmf.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe)
        {System.out.println(fnfe.toString());}
        catch (NumberFormatException fnfe)
        {System.out.println(fnfe.toString());}
        catch (EOFException eofe)
        {System.out.println(eofe.toString());}
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {System.out.println(ioe.toString());}
```

This code take the representation in one string, and result is stored in a file.

https://joseluisbz.wordpress.com/2011/06/22/script-de-clases-rtf-para-jsp-y-php/

Now if you want to obtain the representation of the image file, you can use this:

```
    private void ByteStreamImageString(byte[] ByteStream) {
      this.Format = 0;
      this.High = 0;
      this.Wide = 0;
      this.HexImageString = "Error";
      if (ByteStream[0]== (byte)137 && ByteStream[1]== (byte)80 && ByteStream[2]== (byte)78){
        this.Format = PNG; //PNG
        this.High = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[22],ByteStream[23]);
        this.Wide = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[18],ByteStream[19]);
      }
      if (ByteStream[0]== (byte)255 && ByteStream[1]== (byte)216
          && ByteStream[2]== (byte)255 && ByteStream[3]== (byte)224){
        this.Format = JPG; //JPG
        int PosJPG = 2;
        while (PosJPG < ByteStream.length){
          String M = String.format("%02X%02X", ByteStream[PosJPG+0],ByteStream[PosJPG+1]);
          if (M.equals("FFC0") || M.equals("FFC1") || M.equals("FFC2") || M.equals("FFC3")){
            this.High = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[PosJPG+5],ByteStream[PosJPG+6]);
            this.Wide = this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[PosJPG+7],ByteStream[PosJPG+8]);
          }
          if (M.equals("FFDA")) {
            break;
          }
          PosJPG = PosJPG+2+this.Byte2PosInt(ByteStream[PosJPG+2],ByteStream[PosJPG+3]);
        }
      }
      if (this.Format > 0) {
        this.HexImageString = "";
        int Salto = 0;
        for (int i=0;i < ByteStream.length; i++){
          Salto++;
          this.HexImageString += String.format("%02x", ByteStream[i]);
          if (Salto==64){
            this.HexImageString += "\n"; //To make readable
            Salto = 0;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```